# 'an' or 'a' before the word 'user'?

Tags: vowels, consonants

We learn in English grammar class to use 'a' before words starting with consonants and 'an' before words starting with vowels.

Since for the word 'user' which starts with a vowel, are we supposed to use 'an' or 'a'.

'A user' feels more meaningful than 'an user'.
Which is the correct usage?

Answer (score 1):

It is not so much the letter that matters; it primarily depends on the initial sound of the word which is directly preceded by the article. The noun **user** is phonetically [ˈjuː.zə] or [ˈjuː.zəɹ]. So we see that it starts with [j] which is generally considered to be a consonant sound. Therefore we should say and write **a user** and not "an user" since we use "a" before a word which begins with a consonantal sound.